# HTMLCollection shows when replacing elements in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace an Html(Div) Into Text Element The First i created the conditions you can see it here

**Html**

```
<!-- Replace Text Here-->
<h6 class="idk1"> Replace This  </h6>
<!-- Main Column -->

<div class="js-cp-main-wrp">
<div class="support-2">
<html>stuff here</html>
</div>
<div class="end-cp-wrp">
<html>stuff here</html>
<html>stuff here</html>
<html>stuff here</html>

</div>
</div>
```

**Js Script**

```
    var woahtikcets = document.getElementsByClassName('js-cp-main-wrp');
    const loadthetickets = document.getElementsByClassName('idk1');
```

The run this

```
loadthetickets.replaceWith(woahtikcets)
```

it show me
[object HTMLCollection] ??

this method didn't work it sigh it as undefined ? please help <3

```
 const loadthetickets = document.getElementsByClassName('idk1')[0];
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection`. You can iterate over it and call `replaceWith` on its items: `for (var ticket of loadthetickets) { ticket.replaceWith(...) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not at all certain about what your intention is but `<html>` is not just *some tag*  in HTML. It must be the outer tag ([the root of the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html)) and can therefore only appear once in a document. So, if you replace the `<html>` elements  with other (legal) entities, like `<span>` you will very likely get some results, as you can see below:

```js
 const woahtikcets = document.querySelectorAll('.js-cp-main-wrp span'),
       newtext = document.getElementsByClassName('idk1')[0].textContent;

for (var el of woahtikcets){el.textContent=newtext}
```

```html
<!-- Replace Text Here-->
<h6 class="idk1"> Replace This  </h6>
<!-- Main Column -->

<div class="js-cp-main-wrp">
<div class="support-2">
<span>stuff here</span>
</div>
<div class="end-cp-wrp">
<span>stuff here</span>
<span>stuff here</span>
<span>stuff here</span>

</div>
</div>
```

In case you want the replace operation to work in the opposite direction, you could do the following:

```js
const newtext = document.querySelectorAll('.js-cp-main-wrp')[0].textContent,
      heading = document.getElementsByClassName('idk1');

for (var el of heading){el.textContent=newtext}
```

```html
<!-- Replace Text Here-->
<h6 class="idk1"> Replace This  </h6>
<!-- Main Column -->

<div class="js-cp-main-wrp">
<div class="support-2">
<span>stuff here</span>
</div>
<div class="end-cp-wrp">
<span>stuff here</span>
<span>stuff here</span>
<span>stuff here</span>

</div>
</div>
```